# How would I go about displaying different text and having players choose between two options for a different result?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, and am trying to build a text-based story game. I want there to be two options that the player can choose from, and every time they choose a different option it goes to different text. I know absolutely nothing of how to do this since I started coding python just about 50 minutes ago and still am learning the basics. What could I do to go about this?

Comment: I'm not asking for code; what I'm asking for is a link to the documentation where I could find on help to do this. I haven't been able to find a site that helps me with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation (or recommend them).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example :

```py
def make_the_player_choose_from(things):
    while True:
        choice = input("Choose from " + str(things) + " : ")
        if choice in things:
            return choice
        else:
            print("incorrect choice")


places = ("castle", "village", "dark forest")


print("Your are at a cross-road, there are 3 directions in front of you.")
print("A sign indicate that you can go to :")
print(" - the lovely town of Erydence")
print(" - the stronghold of Lord Xeles")
print(" - the dangerous woods of Chark")
print("Which road will you follow ?")
destination = make_the_player_choose_from(places)

if destination == places[0]:  # castle
    print("You arrive at the door of the fortress, a guard is watching you attentively.")
    print("What do you want to do ?")
    # chat, attack, bribe, sneak past, back to the crossroad, ...
elif destination == places[1]:  # village
    print("The town is completely silent, there is no one to be seen. Where did all the people go ?")
    print("What do you want to do ?")
    # discreetly explore, draw your sword and ask loudly for peasants to come out, observe from a distance, go back, ...
else:  # woods
    print("Entering the woods, you notice that there is a large clearing with a massive rock at its center.")
    print("What do you want to do ?")
    # sing, climb into the trees, progress, cautiously, prepare your bow, ...
```

As you can see, there are nothing too complicated.
I mainly used :

- `input` to get the user to input its choice, wrapped into a function that checks that the input is valid
- `print` to display informations
- conditionals (`if`/`elif`/`else`) to handle the different cases

But this is nothing particularly related to "text-based story games", it is just basic programming.
So start with something simple, make it work, then iteratively augment it.
You could use **variables** to remember previous choices (handle inventory, make certain choices have consequences, ...).
You could use **objects** to store related information together (for example for a place : its name, its description, where it can lead to, what encounters you make there, ...) and have your objects reference each other to make use of that.
You could also use **functions**, either to give a clearer structure to your code (readability) or reuse code (reusability).
Introduce loops to repeat certain operations (spawning X enemies, ...), arithmetical (`+-*/^`) and logical (`and or not ...`) operators to check for certain conditions (`if (player.charisma > 20) and (price > 100): price -= 100`. You could read data from files on the disk to make customization simpler, have a GUI (*graphical user interface*), compile it into an executable that you can distribute later, allow multiplayer or online playing, host it on a web-server, ...

There is no "Python tutorial for beginners wanting to create a text-based game", but there is so many Python tutorials aimed at beginners, so that you can :

- either follow a tutorial and improve your game with what you just learnt, (simpler option)
- or decide what you want your game to have, then follow tutorials on how to implement it (may be much harder, depending on the topic)

But there is no real answer to your question, as some people explained in comments to your question.